# Adding arbitrary zero-padding in tikzpicture ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In this example (from [here](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=AO6)),

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled x ticks = false,
          fixed}%
     ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0.1,1000)
  (0.2,1100)
  (0.3,1200)
  };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the x-axis ticks are printed with just one number after the decimal point, when it's possible:

```
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
```

I would like instead to put zero-padding, to always have the same number of digits (2, in this example) after the point:

```
0.10
0.15
0.20
0.25
0.30
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fixed zerofill` and `precision` may be the keys you are looking for.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled x ticks = false,
          fixed zerofill,precision=2}%
     ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0.1,1000)
  (0.2,1100)
  (0.3,1200)
  };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]