# Zero-padding in tikzpicture ticks with sci number format

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is strictly related to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574488/adding-arbitrary-zero-padding-in-tikzpicture-ticks):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          fixed},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        anchor=north west}%
     ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0.1,1000)
  (0.2,1100)
  (0.3,1200)
  };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The x-axis ticks are:

```
1 x 10^{-1}
1.5 x 10^{-1}
2 x 10^{-1}
```

With the above code, this is the result, regardless of the value of `/pgf/number format/precision`.

I would like instead to have, with `/pgf/number format/precision=3`:

```
1.000 x 10^{-1}
1.500 x 10^{-1}
2.000 x 10^{-1}
```

How is it possible with `/pgf/number format/sci`?

Comment: In this case it is probably `sci zerofill` what you are looking for.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel Yes, thank you, it works. If you want, you can write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for `sci zerofill`. It is just that without further ado in your settings the labels overlap. I added one possible way to address this by making the plot wider and dialing some `xtick distance`. (Strangely even setting the compatibility to `1.17` does not seem to automatically cure this, which may indicate that I am missing something basic.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} %<-consider adding
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          fixed},xtick distance=0.05,
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3,
        /pgf/number format/sci zerofill,
        anchor=north west}%
     ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0.1,1000)
  (0.2,1100)
  (0.3,1200)
  };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. In my example, I simply replaced `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill` with `/pgf/number format/sci zerofill` and it worked. Are they both needed? `xtick distance=0.05` is very useful and I did not need to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`.

Comment: @BowPark Thanks! I think you are right. I was just paying all attention to the overlapping labels so that I forgot to remove the unnecessary key,